# how to get the height of a row in a grid WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a Grid and into one of its cells I am adding and removing User Controls programmatically.The code to do that looks something like this

```
this.mainRegion.Children.Add(RibbonRegion);// mainRegion is  a Grid and Ribbon Region    is a user control   

 Grid.SetRow(RibbonRegion, RegionIndex);
```

Here is the thing I want to get the height of the Row that is RegionIndex so that I can get the RibbonRegion control to fill up alL the available space otherwise there is just too much white space the user control is occupying a very small part of the Row.
I basically want to say something like  UserControl.Height=RowHeight
Can I do that

Comment: Why you doing it in procedural code and not in XAML where you can achieve this easily.

Comment: how can I achieve this is XAML. the requirement is that at runtime based on user interaction various user controls are added to a row in a grid and hidden shown removed or added

Comment: You can add controls in XAML and then can play with Visibility of controls.

Comment: Anyways you can get actualHeight like this `mainRegion.RowDefinitions[RegionIndex].ActualHeight;` and if height is set to constant value you can get it this way - `mainRegion.RowDefinitions[RegionIndex].Height;`.

Comment: no that does not work it returns 0. I have a feeling its because the measure step has not been called yet I am not sure how to go about this

Comment: `ActualHeight` will return current height rendered on UI whereas `Height` returns fixed value set on the row definition. Have you set any height for rowDefinition in which you adding your control?

Comment: Moreover, just set Height in xaml to * (`<RowDefinition Height="*"/>`) so that it occupies available space. It would be helpful if you can post xaml code as well.

Comment: yeah * worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of playing with height in procedural code, I would suggest to put the constraint on height in XAML itself at time of RowDefinitions declaration. ***Set the height to `*` for your row so that it will take all the available space.***

Something like this *(assuming you want to place it in second column)*:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainRegion">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    .......
</Grid>
```